# Join pandas data frames based on columns and column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, join

I'm trying to join two data frames based on multiple columns. However, one of the conditions is not straight forward, because one column in one data frame exists in column of lists in the other data frame. As following

df_a :

[image]

df_b:

[image]

I want to join both data frames based on node,channel,value. However, value is inside a list in column trail

I have tried to create a dictionary from df_a to have the node and channel as keys, but that won't be unique, I added the value as a key but then I couldn't look that value up. Any tip to solve this issue is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried something like: `df_b['value'] = df['trail'].str.partition(',')[0]` - then doing the merge?

Comment: you can explode the list column into multiple rows using explode() function of pandas  and then do a join, then in your result table you can aggregate the column values into a list using groupby

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the reply but the order is not always the same as the length of the list

Comment: @RajatMishra Thank for the reply, I'm working with big data frames and sometimes the trail can have very large number of elements, this is why I was trying to create a lookup dictionary but couldn't figure out how

Comment: I don't get what you mean? Are you saying the `trail` column in `df_b` doesn't always contain the `value` before the first comma?

Comment: @JonClements yes exactly  the order is not always the same

Comment: Right... is it always of the format D-DDD-D ?

Comment: Yes it is always with the same format, and this format is not unique per list so df['trail'] can have [D-DDD-D,A-B-C,C-CCC-C]

Answer (score 1):

Update per comment by @JonClements if not always the first element try:

```
(df_b.assign(value=df_b['trail'].str.split(','))
     .explode('value')
     .merge(df_a, on=['node', 'channel', 'value']))
```

Try, if value is always the first element in trail:

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'node':['a']*4, 
                     'channel':[1,2,1,2],   
                     'wavelength':[555, 666, 555, 666], 
                     'value':['1-111-5', '1-222-6', '1-111-7', '1-222-8']})

df_b = pd.DataFrame({'node':['a']*4,
                     'channel':[1,2,1,2],
                     'trail':['1-111-5,1-a-5,2-r-3', 
                             '1-222-6,2-4-5,1-d-3', 
                             '1-111-7,1-a-2,1-f-t', 
                             '1-222-8,1-e-4'],
                    'power':[10,12,13,12]})

df_out = (df_b.assign(value=df_b['trail'].str.split(',').str[0])
              .merge(df_a, on=['node', 'channel', 'value']))
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
  node  channel                trail  power    value  wavelength
0    a        1  1-111-5,1-a-5,2-r-3     10  1-111-5         555
1    a        2  1-222-6,2-4-5,1-d-3     12  1-222-6         666
2    a        1  1-111-7,1-a-2,1-f-t     13  1-111-7         555
3    a        2        1-222-8,1-e-4     12  1-222-8         666
```

Comment: This is what I suggested in a comment but it seems the value isn't always necessarily the first element splitting by comma